# What is the vulnerability in using a plaintext email confirmation token in Devise?

Tags: ruby, security, devise

Devise uses email confirmation tokens with one-way encryption.

The UX cost to this is that if a new confirmation email is sent, then if a user happens to find an older email and click the link, their token won't work.

What is the security vulnerability that Devise is avoiding with a one-way hashed token? What would be insecure about putting a plaintext token in the database? The only thing I can think of is if someone compromised the database they could then find the token and falsely confirm the email. But...

1. if someone has compromised the database, I think there are more serious problems to worry about at that point
2. all they can do is "falsely" confirm an email address they don't control. What's the benefit of this anyway? The more malicious thing to do is switch an account to use an email address that the attacker controls. But having a plaintext confirmation token wouldn't have anything to do with that.

So, what is the purpose of the encrypted token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Devise 3.1 release announcement](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/08/devise-3-1-now-with-more-secure-defaults/):

> In previous versions, Devise stored the tokens for confirmation, reset
>   password and unlock directly in the database. This meant that somebody
>   with read access to the database could use such tokens to sign in as
>   someone else by, for example, resetting their password.
>
> In Devise 3.1, we store an encrypted token in the database and the
>   actual token is sent only via e-mail to the user.

So that is, at least, the reason the Devise developers saw.

Re your #1: Full database compromise isn’t necessary, just read access to that particular subset of data. This could be achieved via SQL injection, a malicious internal user with database access, or other means.

Re your #2: I’m not entirely certain. Likely they wanted to maintain consistency across confirmation, reset, and unlock token storage.